# ListPlot of Table comes back empty

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to do something I assumed would be simple, but I'm hitting a roadblock and I don't know why. I have the following table:

```
Kerr = Table[{s[[i]]/m[[i]]^2, m[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}]
```

Where `s` and `m` are one-dimensional arrays of the same length, imported from data files. I'm combining them into the table named `Kerr`, and I want to plot that (with `s/m^2` on the x axis and `m` on the y axis. The table looks like this:
[image: Table]

When I try to do `ListPlot[Kerr]`, the axes come back empty. I assume I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but I've no idea what. Any ideas?

Comment: try `Kerr = Table[Flatten@{s[[i]]/m[[i]]^2, m[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}]; ListPlot[Kerr]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that every number in your Kerr list is bracketed with `{`  `}`. `ListPlot` expects a list of the form:
`{{1,1},{2,4},{3,9}}`.
So you just have to remove that innermost brackets which, I think, comes from lists `s` &`m`.

I am not sure how they are written in your data files. 
You can try to rewrite your function in the following way:

```
Kerr = Table[{(s[[i]]/m[[i]]^2)[[1]], m[[i]][[1]]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}]
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!